# Can not access internet through my centos ec2 instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a centos 7 ec2 instance on AWS. it resides in a public subnet which have an internet gateway attached to VPC.

the inbound rules are as follow:

```
Ports   Protocol    Source  ohio-dev-rst-public
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
```

the outbound rules are as follows:

```
5439    tcp sg-06fb92bc4187207c5    ✔
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
22  tcp sg-06fb92bc4187207c5    ✔
```

I need internet to do software updates but I can access the internet and I can't ping.

```
[centos@ip-192-168-3-205 ~]$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol. Add that protocol to your outbound rules and try again.

```
Type: All ICMP 
Protocol: TCP
Port range: 0 - 65535
Destination: Anywhere - 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Added 443 and I can now update the software but still I can not ping and receive data though I added ICMP to both inboud and outbound rules.

Comment: Your target may not have ICMP turned on. They, like you, can enable or disable ICMP on their firewall. If they have it disabled, then you will not be able to ping them, even if you enable it on your side

Answer (score 0):

when you create an EC2 instance by using the console, by default all the outgoing traffic are enabled.

It is tricky to say what ports the software updates uses. In my opinion, it may vary depend on the operating system that you are using.

I would suggest to start with enabling the following ports and see if you can get the software updates running again.

80 - HTTP

443 - HTTPS

21 - FTP

All Ports- ICMP (ping)

Hope this helps.